# Extract data from Summit FT

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way for Excel to extract data from Summit FT system through some VBA code or API?

I have an Excel file that requires me to export four different views of Summit to paste into an Excel template that's filled with formulas. I wonder if I could streamline the process by extracting the data by code.

Comment: Please make your question a bit more concrete. What kind of data are you trying to paste? Can you provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You could use Summit eToolkit Excel VBA APIs to communicate with backend to export the fetched data. Summit FT use Summit eToolkit C# APIs to communicate with the backend to display data.